# Keep running a program in terminal over SSH after "Write failed: Broken pipe"

Tags: command-line, ssh

How can I keep a program on a VPS running after SSH session times out?

Comment: I think you have to run it like `nohup YOURCOMMAND`. Not 100% sure though, try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**nohup**

you can use `nohup YOURCOMMAND` to prevent the termination of your ssh connection to kill your command. (@byte-commander mentioned it in a comment earlier)

Answer (score 4):

**screen** or **tmux**

you can use `screen` or `tmux` to allow processes to run in the background, detach them from your session and later re-attach them.

I personally like them better than `nohup` because of the control you have through being able to re-attach those `screen`-/`tmux`-sessions later.

A nice wrapper around `screen` or `tmux` is `byobu` (which defaults to using `tmux`). You can install it by typing `apt-get install byobu` at a command line.